Reading some files is extremely slow in NVMe SSD
I bought Seagate FireCuda 530 2TB ZP2000GM3A013 in Jan 2022.
I started having this issue recently:

CrystalDiskMark performs fast.

CrystalDiskInfo and SMART reports says everything is good

When I try to write file, it's fast

When I try to copy some file from SSD, some directory copies super fast (500 MB/s) while some directly copies incredibly slow. These directory contains multiple 10 * 1 GB files and they copy at 10 MB/s.

When copying these problematic files, disk activity get 100% and system start hanging.


My questions:

Is it bad sector issue? What's the best way to fix it?

Or, should I be safe and buy a new SSD? Money is not a problem. It's for work and I can't afford to lose data. I have backups but I do them only 2-3 times per year.


SMART Reports:




@JoepvanSteen I added SMART reports. Yes, these files are media file and never modified since I got my SSD.

@JoepvanSteen I have Victoria but it's very hard to use. I don't find any document either. Everything is in Russian.

@JoepvanSteen Sorry about the confusion. I meant documentation is in Russian. So I can't understand how to use it

To restore the speed you can run once a month this:
CHKDSK C: /SCAN /PERF /R
CHKDSK D: /SCAN /PERF /R
...

What it does, it inspects every allocated file, which in turn makes the SSD read the contents and run the ECC error correcting algorithm on it. If too many errors are found, it will move it to another page, all automatically. This is done by the SSD's firmware and not by the CHKDSK command itself. We use CHKDSK here in lack of another tool.
Alternatively you can run off a bootable Linux stick:
dd if=/dev/nvmep01s1 of=/dev/null bs=32MB

If you don't do this periodically and wait for the drive to realize the ECC when you're using the drive normally, then there is additional time needed to relocate the contents which in turn makes it look very slow.

Thanks for the tip. I ended up doing low level format using a bootable Ubuntu LTS version and this website as a guide https://tinyapps.org/docs/nvme-sanitize.html
Shouldn't Seagate Firmware do NAND cells refresh internally? I think those new NVME drives lack overprovisioning support and such basic feature to refresh old NAND cell.
The problem is known from times of Samsung EVO 840
Also, I see now that Seagate SSD drives are kinda vanishing from retailer stores. SSDs for data centers as well.
Their RMA procedure is a joke. You will get used, refurbished drive and hope for the best.

I read that data center class NVMe drives actually have firmware features to refresh data on NAND cells. They were most likely disabled for customer grade NVME drives. At the very least their Seagate Tools, should have ability to run a "Refresh health" scan and fix that.

The "CHKDSK C: /SCAN /PERF /R" under Windows is really good. Thanks. I didn't know you can use it for SSD or NVMe drives.

I have exactly the same SSD NVMe drive and the same issue. I bought it around 3 years ago and use it to store games. It came with 03 firmware and later I updated it to 05. The drive has no overprovisioning, Seagate Tools does not have such option.
The drive is kept around 60-70% full of its maximum capacity. Some of my games were installed a year or 2 years ago. Now I see problems when I try to verify them, or patch them. Loading times are also slow on some games. Seagate drive speed drops to like 20MB - 30MB and 100ms - 1000ms response time when verifying game or coping a game to another NVME drive. The speed should be 4GB - 6GB.
My 7 years old Samsung SATA SSD does not do that even for old files and keeps reading speed as of 250MB - 300MB and response time 4ms - 6ms, which is good speed for SATA SSD.
My old Samsung has 10% overprovisioning, and Samsung has its own SSD controller, not the Phison copy.
I'm not sure what to do with this Seagate drive. I suspect the problem is with Seagate's firmware since it should refresh discharging cells or prevent of whatever the issue is with it.
Should I RMA it?
I doubt support will do anything, they probably will send me the my own drive back to me, claiming they don't see the issue.
Benchmark like CrystakDiskMark don't show the problem.
Maybe I should reformat it, but then even if problem goes away, it will probably comeback after some time. And I will loose all data, I don't have where to backup it. Coping 1.2 TB at 20MB- 30MB speed would take many hours, even days. I'm really disappointed with this drive.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

I'm not sure when this website got so formal. It used to be community driven and about helping people. Now it's more formal than corporation.
This subject is not really in form of question either: "Reading some files is extremely slow in NVMe SSD".
And my post was directly connected to the same problem and exactly same SSD NVMe drive.
I couldn't add my post as comments to the "answer", because my "reputation level" is too low.

https://superuser.com/questions/1856633/reading-some-files-is-extremely-slow-in-nvme-ssd/1860817#comment2944009_1856647
